# Answer'd but why? Mysql 1st query runs the second doesn't need to understand why?

Tags: mysql, subquery

This SQL query works but the second one does not can someone please explain why and or how to make it work?

The first works off of row based selections the second i want all the colums and rows more of a global average. The name may have 1 to X amount of entries so it must be group'd by name.

```
SELECT NAME,
       AVERAGE,
       AD1, AD2, AD3, AD4, AD5, AD6,
       (AD1 + AD2 + AD3 + AD4 + AD5 + AD6) AS TOTAL_AD
FROM ( SELECT
    NAME,
    AVERAGE,
    (AVG1-AVERAGE) AS AD1,
    (AVG2-AVERAGE) AS AD2,
    (AVG3-AVERAGE) AS AD3,
    (AVG4-AVERAGE) AS AD4,
    (AVG5-AVERAGE) AS AD5,
    (AVG6-AVERAGE) AS AD6
    FROM P_AVG ) AS T
ORDER BY NAME;
```

Runs as expected.

```
SELECT NAME,
       AVG(AVERAGE),
       AD1, AD2, AD3, AD4, AD5, AD6,
       (AD1 + AD2 + AD3 + AD4 + AD5 + AD6) AS TOTAL_AD
FROM ( SELECT
    NAME,
    AVG(AVERAGE),
    (AVG(AVG1)-AVG(AVERAGE)) AS AD1,
    (AVG(AVG2)-AVG(AVERAGE)) AS AD2,
    (AVG(AVG3)-AVG(AVERAGE)) AS AD3,
    (AVG(AVG4)-AVG(AVERAGE)) AS AD4,
    (AVG(AVG5)-AVG(AVERAGE)) AS AD5,
    (AVG(AVG6)-AVG(AVERAGE)) AS AD6
    FROM P_AVG GROUP BY NAME ) AS T;
```

Mysql returns this error for the query which the column is there.

## 1054 - Unknown column 'AVERAGE' in 'field list'

Does not run and returns error.

This fixed it but why?

```
SELECT NAME,
       AD,
       AD1, AD2, AD3, AD4, AD5, AD6,
       (AD1 + AD2 + AD3 + AD4 + AD5 + AD6) AS TOTAL_AD
FROM ( SELECT
    NAME,
    (AVG(AVERAGE)) AS AD,
    (AVG(AVG1)-AVG(AVERAGE)) AS AD1,
    (AVG(AVG2)-AVG(AVERAGE)) AS AD2,
    (AVG(AVG3)-AVG(AVERAGE)) AS AD3,
    (AVG(AVG4)-AVG(AVERAGE)) AS AD4,
    (AVG(AVG5)-AVG(AVERAGE)) AS AD5,
    (AVG(AVG6)-AVG(AVERAGE)) AS AD6
    FROM P_AVG GROUP BY NAME ) AS T;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your query the error is caused by the absence of a proper alias for   `(AVG(AVERAGE))`

pratically you are selecting by the outer select a column name that not exist

try  adding a proper alias ad this column  eg:

```
  AVG(AVERAGE) AVERAGE
```

.

```
  SELECT NAME,
         AVG(AVERAGE),
         AD1, AD2, AD3, AD4, AD5, AD6,
         (AD1 + AD2 + AD3 + AD4 + AD5 + AD6) AS TOTAL_AD
  FROM ( 
      SELECT
      NAME,
      AVG(AVERAGE) AVERAGE,
      (AVG(AVG1)-AVG(AVERAGE)) AS AD1,
      (AVG(AVG2)-AVG(AVERAGE)) AS AD2,
      (AVG(AVG3)-AVG(AVERAGE)) AS AD3,
      (AVG(AVG4)-AVG(AVERAGE)) AS AD4,
      (AVG(AVG5)-AVG(AVERAGE)) AS AD5,
      (AVG(AVG6)-AVG(AVERAGE)) AS AD6
      FROM P_AVG 
      GROUP BY NAME ) AS T;
```